# Replacing items in a string that match keys in a dict

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, replace

I'm trying to replace characters in a SQL query string `OR NOT "[low_level_rand_num]"="[rand_num]"` with keys in a dict:

```
replacements = {
    '"[low_level_rand_num]"': str(random.randint(1, 13)),
    '"[rand_num]"': str(random.randint(13, 26)),
    '"[comment]"': random.choice(["--", "/*", "#", "*/", "'", '"', "`", "-"]),
    '"[rand_string]"': "asdf",
    '"[query]"': "test_col",
    '"[big_int_1]"': str(random.randint(10000000000, 99999999999)),
    '"[big_int_2]"': str(random.randint(10000000000, 99999999999)),
    '"[encoding]"': random.choice(["utf8", "utf16", "utf32", "ascii"]),
    '"[sleeper]"': str(random.randint(3, 9))
}
```

Using the `string.replace()` function like so:

```
def build_payloads(template):
    replacements = {
        '"[low_level_rand_num]"': str(random.randint(1, 13)),
        '"[rand_num]"': str(random.randint(13, 26)),
        '"[comment]"': random.choice(["--", "/*", "#", "*/", "'", '"', "`", "-"]),
        '"[rand_string]"': rand_string_gen(),
        '"[query]"': random_column(),
        '"[big_int_1]"': str(random.randint(10000000000, 99999999999)),
        '"[big_int_2]"': str(random.randint(10000000000, 99999999999)),
        '"[encoding]"': random.choice(["utf8", "utf16", "utf32", "ascii"]),
        '"[sleeper]"': str(random.randint(3, 9))
    }
    for k in replacements.keys():
        if k in template:
            print template.replace(k, replacements[k])
```

However, everytime I run this function, I get the output:

```
OR NOT 7="[rand_num]"
OR NOT "[low_level_rand_num]"=21
```

It seems that it's replacing the strings, but it's not keeping them replaced, what am I doing wrong to where the strings will not stay replaced and how can I fix this issue and get my expected output of `OR NOT 7=21`?

Comment: [``str.replace``](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) -> ``Return a copy of the string with all occurrences of substring old replaced by new.`` You will need to replace your string with the result of str.replace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String replacements are not done in-place, update the template after replacing:

```
...
for k in replacements:
    if k in template:
        template = template.replace(k, replacements[k])
        print template
```

As a side note, when iterating on dictionary keys, you can drop the `.keys` call as iterating on the dictionary directly will run through its keys.

Answer (score 0):

You're just outputting the result of the replacement, `template` itself doesn't change.

```
template = "foo"
print template.replace("foo","bar") #outputs 'bar'
print template #outputs 'foo'
template = template.replace("foo","bar")
print template #outputs 'bar'
```